# how to describe or highlight certain points in charts and give hyperlink on that points

Tags: javascript, html, svg, javascript-framework, protovis

I am using protovis for charts....I am kind of a new here...
What I want to do is I want to show [area charts](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/area.html). And in that I want to show few points with different color or highlight some point...And when I click on that point I want to open up new page or show some panel on same page...Any idea how to do that with protovis? If it is  not possible with the protovis can you suggest some other framework which does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for is something like this:

```
vis.add(pv.Area)
    .data(data)
    .left(function(d) x(d.x))
    .height(function(d) y(d.y))
    .anchor("top").add(pv.Dot)
        .size(20)
        .event("click", function (d) alert("Clicked point " + this.index));
```

The important part is the `.event("click", function (d) some_code())` bit. If you're using pure JavaScript, you would do `.event("click", function (d) { return some_code(); })`.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/KNQVf/) a working (albeit sloppy) example.

You might also want to note that Protovis is being superseded by Mike Bostock's [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).

Comment: Great. You should indicate that by "accepting" the answer (click the check box outline to the left of the answer). For details, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask (click *show more*).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about protovis, but you can do that in html.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

I hope you are looking for something like this.